# DHCP Relay on Cisco ASA over site-to-site VPN

Tags: cisco-asa, dhcp

How do I get the DHCP relay function of a Cisco ASA working over a site-to-site VPN?

The ops center is behind a 5510 ASA with a 3560 core switch. The DHCP server is at IP 10.0.10.153.

The remote location is behind a 5505 ASA, with no layer 3 switches or routers at the site, just a layer 2 switch behind the ASA. The local network is 10.29.8.0/24 with the ASA's inside IP being 10.29.8.1.

A VPN is set up between the two locations and traffic between 10.29.8.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/8 is being tunneled. There's no problem in reaching the DHCP server from that local network (10.29.8.x to 10.0.153) so the connection is fine between the two as long as the IP is already present and we're routing between the two.

I've set the DHCP Relay Agent on the remote ASA as follows:

```
dhcprelay server 10.0.10.153 outside
dhcprelay enable inside
dhcprelay setroute inside
dhcprelay timeout 60
```

Where my problem is, I believe, is that I have to make some changes to the ACL for the crypto map, but I'm getting very confused reading through the documentation and posts I can find on this subject.

Comment: What version of code is each running? There was a later bug that changed how the relay agent functions (setting giaddr to the interface asking for the address) In all cases, you're better of not using an ASA for dhcp *at all*.

Comment: 8.2(5) 58. That's the newest (at least as of a few weeks ago) on the 8.2 line. The ASA is really my only option here... I'm not going to be able to put a layer 3 switch in these locations, nor will they anytime soon be getting branch servers or something else that could provide DHCP locally.